# Python DIscordbot using MongoDB

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, database, mongodb

i tried to switch from json to MongoDB and most things worked. However the bancommand is not working because python does not store userids into the variables longer or not take it from the Database. So everytime i run the command it print out that the ID is not in the VAriable but the ID and the Name is stored into the Database. Hopefully someone is able to help me with this. Here is my full code:

```
import pymongo
import json
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

with open("mongosetup.json") as file:
    setupfile = json.load(file)

    # ==> DISCORDBOT SETUP <== #
    botprefix = setupfile.get("Discordbot Prefix")
    token = setupfile.get("Discordbot Token")

    # ==> DATABASE SETUP <== #
    url = setupfile.get("Database url")
    databasename = setupfile.get("Database Name")
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=botprefix, case_insensitive=True, self_bot=False, Intents=discord.Intents.all())
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(url)
    mydb = myclient[databasename]
    print(myclient.list_database_names())
    dblist = myclient.list_database_names()

    if databasename in dblist:
        print("The database exists.")
    collection = mydb["UserData"]
    bannedusers = mydb["BannedUser"]



    @bot.command(name="AddDB")
    async def addtodb(ctx):

        try:
            userdata = {"_id": ctx.author.id, "Username": ctx.message.author.name}
            if ctx.author.id not in userdata:
                collection.insert_one(userdata)
                await ctx.send("Your Username and your UserID where stored into our Datebase sucessfully! \n"
                               f"Saved Data: {userdata}")

        except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
            await ctx.send("You cant add yourself twice in our Database. This User alredy exist!")

    @bot.command(name="ban")
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
    async def banuser(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
        userdata = {"_id": member.id, "Username": member.display_name}
        data = collection.find_one({"_id": member.id})

        if data is None:
            post = {userdata}
            collection.insert_one(post)

        print(member.id)
        if member.id not in userdata:
            print("Not in userdata")
            bannedusers.insert_one(userdata)

        elif member.id in bannedusers:
            await ctx.send(f"Trying to ban the User {member.display_name}...")
            try:
                await member.ban(reason=reason)
                await ctx.send("Banned this user Sucessfully")
            except:
                await ctx.send("error")

    @bot.event
    async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send("Please pass in all required Arguments :rolling_eyes:")
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send("You dont have all the required Permissions :angry:")


    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')



bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't look for a variable (member.id) inside a dictionary. Also I dont see the reason to have `if member.id not in userdata:` because member.id will always be in userdata because you specify that member.id should be inside userdata.

If I understood correctly, you want to ban users, then store it in a mongodb.
You can easily do this by doing it like this:

```
@bot.command(name="ban")
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def banuser(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    userdata = {"_id": member.id, "Username": member.display_name} #stores all values in a variable
    data = collection.find_one({"_id": member.id}) #looks for the user in the collection db

    if data is None: #if user doesnt exist in the user db
        collection.insert_one(userdata) #add the user
        
    await ctx.send(f"Trying to ban the User {member.display_name}...")
    try:
        await member.ban(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send("Banned this user Sucessfully")
        bannedusers.insert_one(userdata) #adds the user to the banned db
    except:
        await ctx.send("error")
```

Hope this helps, and just ask any questions if you have any!